# How to free allocated memory in a binary tree in C

Tags: c, tree, malloc, binary-tree, free

I am having trouble with a function in my C program.  The purpose of the program is to:

- Read integers from a binary file into an array
- Sort these numbers using a binary tree
- Do some other stuff
- Free all memory that you allocated using malloc();

I've got everything working except for being able to free my binary tree.  Here are my structures for the tree and node (a.k.a. leaf).

```
typedef struct Node *NodeP;
typedef struct Tree *TreeP;

// Definition of a tree
    struct Tree
    {
        NodeP root;
    }Tree;

    // Definition of a node
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        NodeP L, R;
    }Node;
```

In my program, I have used malloc to allocate memory for my tree and for each individual node.  So I call a function to free the tree and all of its nodes.

```
/*
 * Frees the memory allocated for
 * each node
 */
void freeNode(NodeP p)
{
    if(p == NULL) return;
    freeNode(p->L);
    freeNode(p->R);
    free(p);
}

/*
 * Frees the memory allocated
 * for the tree
 */
TreeP freeTree(TreeP tree)
{
    if(tree->root == NULL)
        free(tree);
    else
    {
        freeNode(tree->root);
        free(tree);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

When I run this program, my debugger is giving me this error.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

I've tried mentally going through each iteration of the recursion, and I can't find why it's giving me an error.  I'm thinking it's falling off the edge of the tree at the edge cases?  I'm not sure.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is a link to download the full program.  I included a README and the binary files I am working with.  One is only 10 integers in length, the other is 20000 in length.  Thanks for your help so far!

https://copy.com/902v0bMv8DtIMUrc

Comment: why don't you take a look at the call stack to realize, where the problem is? (at least, at what level)

Comment: I can see two unusual constructs (the `p = NULL` in `freeNode` and returning `NULL` from `freeTree`), but neither of these should be the source of your problems (but I'd get rid of them anyway). I suspect you've trashed your heap somewhere else, and the problem is only manifest when you walk the tree to free the nodes. Look elsewhere.

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with the implementation, so you'll have to use the debugger with a small tree to find the problem. It's possible that the tree is malformed, e.g. multiple parents point to the same child, or some pointers are not properly initialized, but those types of problems are not in the code that you shared. Side note: the line `p = NULL;` at the end of `freeNode` does nothing and should be removed.

Comment: @ user590028 I'm not sure what you mean by trashing the heap somewhere else.  I don't do anything with memory allocation outside of the initial call to malloc and the functions I posted.

Comment: if you provide full implementation someone can help you

Comment: @Hotsaucejalapeno He/she typed faster than I did, but the comments are essentially identical -- the problem is not in the code that you posted. The problem (most likely) occurs while building the tree.

Comment: Did you really allocate memory for the root struct containing a single pointer, that you `free()`? It's a strange way of doing it: the tree root is usually a pointer to the first node.

Comment: $64: Did you ensure all leaf nodes had NULL for both their left and right child tree pointers when you constructed that tree ? And the `freeTree` function should only need `if (tree) { freeNode(tree->root); free(tree); }` btw. And in your linked code, `malloc(sizeof(TreeP));` is **not** what you want. That allocates exactly the memory for the size of a pointer, not the size of a `Tree` node, a mistake you likely wouldn't have made had you not ill-advisedly hidden your pointer types in typedefs.

Comment: @WhozCraig I did set the Left and Right pointers to NULL when I created a new node (in the insertTreeNode() function).  I fixed the sizeof(TreeP) problem and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah that is how we were taught in Data Structures I.  In the hopes of making the code more reusable?  I guess if I wanted to handle different data or include more things inside the structure I could.

Comment: The code would be much easier to read without the typedefs for struct pointers.

Comment: @chqrlie I see this now.  I will keep this in mind in my future programs :)

Comment: @Hotsaucejalapeno I don't think that's the reason for having a root struct that only points to the tree. I think it is because it is easier for a beginner to assign a new first node in the root struct, than to pass a `**` pointer that would otherwise be required to alter the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is confusion here:

```
// Definition of a tree
struct Tree
{
    NodeP root;
}Tree;

// Definition of a node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    NodeP L, R;
}Node;
```

The definitions above define variables, not types!

There is a bug here:

```
TreeP newTree()
{
    TreeP tree = (TreeP) malloc(sizeof(TreeP));
    tree->root = NULL;
    return tree;
}
```

It should read `TreeP tree = malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));`.  A good example of why it is a bad idea to typedef structure pointers.  Since Tree holds only a single pointer, this is not causing any problem, but it should be fixed.

Here is **THE** bug:

```
/*
 * Creates a new node in the tree
 */
void insertTreeNode(TreeP tree, int data)
{
    NodeP p = tree->root;
    Boolean b = FALSE;

    /*  Creates a node and tests for errors  */
    NodeP node = (NodeP) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(node == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed! \n");
    else
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->L = NULL;
        node->R = NULL;

        /*  Inserts in empty tree case  */
        if(tree->root == NULL)
            tree->root = node;
        else
        {
            /*  Inserts in any other case  */
            while(p != NULL && b != TRUE)
            {
                if(node->data >= p->data)
                {
                    if(p->R == NULL)
                    {
                        p->R = node;
                        b = TRUE;
                    }
                    else p = p->R;
                }
                if(node->data <= p->data) // replace this line with else
                {
                    if(p->L == NULL)
                    {
                        p->L = node;
                        b = TRUE;
                    }
                    else p = p->L;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You must link the new node to the left or to the right of node p but not in both subtrees if `p->data == data`.

There might be other bugs, but this one bites!

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was what I was doing wrong.  I fixed the other things you mentioned too.  :)

Comment: @Hotsaucejalapeno `struct Tree* tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));` would be a reasonable alternative., or just  `Tree* tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));` if you fix your struct decls to actually declare types `Tree` and `Node`. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I would prefer `Tree *tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));` style.  Tacking the `*` to the type is error prone, as in the classic `Tree* L,R;` for which `TreeP L,R;` is a bad solution for other reasons.